# watchkit - how to use my numbers with an image

Tags: string, image, watchkit

i have following code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    NSMutableString *Row = [NSMutableString new];
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        [Row appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", numbers[j][i]]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@\n", Row);
}
```

with this i get the following output:

6473
7354
9835
6475

i have 16 images in groups on my WKInterfaceController and now i want to display an image for each number . for example, a 4 = image4.png, 8 = image8.png.

first line is: image6 image 4 image7 and image3 and so on.

how can i get there?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the image on  instance of your imageView (`WKInterfaceImage`)

```
yourimageView.setImage(UIImage(named: "image name string"));
```

The above code of yours just give the imageName as per your approach. If there are multiple `WKInterfaceImage` objects in your storyboard then you need to make outlets for each of them and then set the image accordingly. Since `WatchKit` do not support Collection outlets so you need to make outlet for every `WKInterfaceObject`. You can set the image from Inspector to if image is supposed to be same always for a particular object.